# Почему не переименовывается файл?

Tags: java, ооп, классы

Есть такая функция:

```
// корректировать имена файлов
private void correctFileName(){
    String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
    String name = file.getName();
    String newFileName = fileName.substring(0);

    // проверка на наличие пробелов между исполнителем и названием
    if(fileName.contains("-") && !fileName.contains(" - ")){
        newFileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.indexOf("-"));
        newFileName += " - ";
        newFileName += fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("-")+1);
    }
    // проверка на -kissvk.com
    if(newFileName.contains("-kissvk")){
        int endIndex = newFileName.length() - 15;
        newFileName = newFileName.substring(0, endIndex);
        newFileName += ".mp3";
    }
    System.out.println(newFileName);   
    File result = new File(newFileName);
    System.out.println(file.renameTo(result));
    file = result;
}
```

Она работает, файл переименовывается. Теперь есть такая функция:

```
// корректировать имена файлов
private void correctFileName(){
    String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
    String name = file.getName();
    String newFileName;
    
    // Если песня из альбома
    if(isAlbum){
        newFileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length()-name.length());
        newFileName += number;
        newFileName += ". ";
        newFileName += artist;
        newFileName += " - ";
        newFileName += songName;
        newFileName += ".mp3";
    }
    else{
        newFileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length()-name.length());
        newFileName += artist;
        newFileName += " - ";
        newFileName += songName;
        newFileName += ".mp3";           
    }
    
    System.out.println(newFileName);   
    File result = new File(newFileName);
    System.out.println(file.renameTo(result));
    file = result;
}
```

Это методы класса, isAlbum, file - его поля. Второй метод не работает, фактического переименования нет, результат renameTo() - false. Что не так с ней? Почему первая работает, а вторая нет?
`System.out.println(newFileName)` выдает одинаковый результат.

Comment: Если `выдает одинаковый результат.`, то должно одинаково работать. А что выводит в `System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());` и `System.out.println(result.getAbsolutePath());`?

Comment: Для файла Framing Hanley-Hear Me Now-kissvk.com 
D:\Framing Hanley-Hear Me Now-kissvk.com.mp3
D:\Framing Hanley - Hear Me Now.mp3

Answer (score 1):

Это специфика самого [renameTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29)

> Renames the file denoted by this abstract pathname. Many aspects of
> the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: The
> rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem
> to another, it might not be atomic, and it might not succeed if a file
> with the destination abstract pathname already exists. The return
> value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation
> was successful.

Вам нужно проверять результат операции. И на существование уже этого файла в указанном пути, не говоря о платформе и прочие.

Существует альтернатива [переименованию](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000183/reliable-file-renameto-alternative-on-windows) файла это [перемещение](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

пример взят из ответа.

```
String fileName = "MyFile.txt";

try {
    Files.move(new File(fileName).toPath(), new File(fileName).toPath(), java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел корень зла. Я брал `artist`, `songName` из ID3v1, они в ANSI-кодировке. Функция не брала эти слова. Потом поменял на char, тоже не переименовывала. Заработала, когда передавал слова в String

Comment: мда, сильно однако. Ничего бывает.